# What resources are being requested by the howler.js library?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, audio, howler.js

I am writing an interactive ebook with sound for use in Apple ibooks.  I have been experimenting with the howler.js sound library to handle the needed sound events.  In doing some testing, I included the howler library in the first page of my ebook.  I did not load or play any sound file.  I did not even make any calls to the library in my script.  All I did was to include the library in the head section of the document.

```
<script src="javascript/howler.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Yet when ibooks was open and the ipad was put to sleep and then reawakened, it always had audio play controls present.  I realized later this was from the howler library and also realized that resources were being used even when the ibooks and even the ipad itself was supposed to be asleep.  It was as if the howler library had requested the audio hardware and software controls and held onto them and used them until the ibooks app was closed regardless of the state of the app or of the ipad.  The full battery was completely used when the ipad was asleep in a very short period of time.

This leads me to my question(s).

What hardware resources does the howler.js library request?  And does the library make those requests on a continual basis even when it has not been called nor is anything requesting any sound event whatsoever?  And is there a way to stop the library from requesting resources when the app is not active with the focus or when the ipad is asleep?

Comment: Which version of howler.js are you using?

Comment: howler.js v1.1.26 and I'm using the mini one.

Comment: Does this continual using of resources have anything to do with the note on the howler documentation about the ios?  And will "Howler.iOSAutoEnable = false;" fix the issue?